# UIRefreshControl is not displayed on iOS 17 (received offscreen beginRefreshing warning)

Tags: ios, tableview, uirefreshcontrol, xcode15, ios17

I tried to run a simple code which is running perfectly on iOS 14/15/16, but now while using Xcode 15 on iOS 17 this is not working anymore. I will attach the code below displaying a table view with a `UIRefreshControl` which will run `beginRefreshing()` before a fetch request, but the refresh control is not showing anymore on iOS 17 and I'm getting this warning which is saying that the refresh control received offscreen beginRefreshing.

[image]

Here is the code with a simulated fetch request using `DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter` displaying a simple table view. If you try to run it on iOS 17, the refresh control will not be displayed before the simulated fetch request.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    private let tableView = UITableView()
    private let cellIdentifier = "cellIdentifier"
    private let data = ["Cell 1", "Cell 2"]
    private let refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        configureTableView()
        
        refreshControl.beginRefreshing()
        
        // Simulate fetch request
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1, execute: {
            self.setDataSource()
        })
    }
    
    private func configureTableView() {
        tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: cellIdentifier)
        refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(refreshData), for: .valueChanged)
        tableView.refreshControl = refreshControl
        
        tableView.frame = view.bounds
        tableView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
        view.addSubview(tableView)
    }
    
    private func setDataSource() {
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.reloadData()
        refreshControl.endRefreshing()
    }
    
    // MARK: - UITableViewDataSource
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return data.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = data[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }
    
    // MARK: - Refresh Control Action
    
    @objc private func refreshData() {
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2.0) {
            self.refreshControl.endRefreshing()
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
}
```

Do you know any fix for this in order to run the same way even on iOS 17, without using `viewDidAppear` or `viewWillAppear` methods, because I want the fetch to be called only once per view life cycle?

Comment: By definition viewDidLoad() is called when the view hierarchy is loaded into memory, hence it is off screen. What is the reason for which you don't want to use viewDidAppear()?

Comment: @CosteaBogdan Because `viewDidAppear` is called multiple times for eg when you pop from other vc, or when you present something and then dismiss it. The begin refreshing should be done once after the first load of the view is done.

Comment: If that is the case, in my opinion you should move your code to viewDidAppear() and have a mechanism which checks if you've already fetched the data.

Comment: Yes, I agree with you. Let's see if there is another approach

Answer (score 6):

With iOS 17, apple introduced a new lifecycle method: viewisappearing, it also has iOS 13+ backwards compatibility.

refreshControl.beginRefreshing() should be called in viewIsAppearing
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/4195485-viewisappearing